# Get JSON results in ASP.NET CORE 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The controller´s method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetItem()
{
    List<SelectListItem> drop = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem{Value="Superman",Text="Superman"},
        new SelectListItem{Value="Batman",Text="Batman"},
        new SelectListItem{Value="Wonderwoman",Text="Wonderwoman"}
    };
    return Json(drop);
}
```

The HTML´s select:

```
<select id="ddlCustomers"></select>
```

The AJAX´s call:

```
var ddlCustomers = $("#ddlCustomers");
ddlCustomers.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0" disabled = "disabled">loading.........</option>');
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Usuario/GetItem",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $('#ddlCustomers').append('<option value=' + data[i].Value + '>' + data[i].Text + '</option > ');
        }
    }
});
```

It´s hitting the controller but returning/populating the select as UNDEFINED.

Any helps ? Thank you!

please note: this is a WEB APP not WEB API.

Comment: Have you checked the response of the ajax call ? In chrome you can press F12, in order developer tools to appear. Then refresh your page and at the _Network_ tab you should see the ajax call request and response.  What the response contains ?

Comment: @Christos the response contains: [{disabled: false, group: null, selected: false, text: "Superman", value: "Superman"},…]
0: {disabled: false, group: null, selected: false, text: "Superman", value: "Superman"}
1: {disabled: false, group: null, selected: false, text: "Batman", value: "Batman"}
2: {disabled: false, group: null, selected: false, text: "Wonderwoman", value: "Wonderwoman"}

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response you get, you should change this:

```
'<option value=' + data[i].Value + '>' + data[i].Text + '</option > '
```

with this:

```
'<option value=' + data[i].value + '>' + data[i].text + '</option > '
```

By the way you don't have to select HTML element with id `ddlCustomer` in each step of your for loop. You can use `ddlCustomers` variable who holds a reference to the element you want to append the options you have

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     ddlCustomers.append('<option value=' + data[i].value + '>' + data[i].text + '</option > ');
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, it´s working now! You´re the man!  Anyway, is there a better and safety approach  ?

Comment: @BerBar you are welcome. I am glad that I helped. It's ok.

Comment: is this GET method and call the safety way avoiding be used by third parties?

Comment: Nope, if someone check the network traffic, as you debugged the problem using developer tools, fairly easily would see the corresponding call. Then by using the corresponding absolute URL _http(s)://domainname/Usuario/GetItem_ would fetch the corresponding data. Apparently, we are speaking for users we see your application in a public network. If you deploy your application in a private network and allow access only to resources in this network, this can be done only from users inside this private network.

Comment: I see the point. I will do a ressearch regarding this matter. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

JS is case sensitive, try

```
$('#ddlCustomers').append('<option value=' + data[i].value + '>' + data[i].text + '</option > ');
```